# Running time of simple algorithm using unfolding technique

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> Consider the following recursive algorithm $Trump$, which takes as input an integer  $n ≥ 1$, **which is a power of** $\textbf{2}$:
>
> > $\textbf{Algorithm} \hspace{2mm} Trump(n):\\  
> > \textbf{if }n = 1 \\
> > \textbf{then} \text{ order chicken nuggets} \\
> > \textbf{else if } n = 2 \\
> > \quad \quad \textbf{then} \text{ drink one pint of beer} \\
> > \quad \quad \textbf{else} \textit{ print } \thinspace ``\text{I am fabulous''}; \\
> > \quad \quad\hspace{2em} Trump(n/2) \\
> > \quad \quad \textbf{endif} \\
> > \textbf{endif}
> > $
>
> For $n$ a power of $2$, let $T(n)$ be the number of times you print $``\text{I am fabulous''}$ when running algorithm $Trump(n)$. Which of the following is true?
>
> **(a)** $T(n) = \log n - 1$ for all $n \ge 2$
>   (b) $T(n) = \log n - 1$ for all $n \ge 1$
>   (c) $T(n) = \log n$ for all $n \ge 2$
>   (d) $T(n) = n-2$ for all $n \ge 2$

The answer is **(a).**

I got **(c):**

$T(1) = 0$
$T(2) = 0$
$T(n) \le 1 + T(n/2)$, if $n \ge 2$  $\quad(1)$

By unfolding:
Assume $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k \ge 0$

If we replace $n$ by $n/2$ in $(1)$, we get:
$T(n/2) \le 1 + T(n/2^2)$

So,
$T(n) \le 1 + T(n/2)$
$T(n) \le 1 + (1 + T(n/2^2))$
$\ldots$
$T(n) \le k + T(n/2^k)$

Substitute $2^k$ for $n$, we get:
$T(n) \le k + T(2^k/2^k)$
$T(n) \le \log n + T(1) \quad\quad 2^k \implies k = \log n$
$T(n) \le \log n + 0$
$T(n) \le \log n$, hence **(c)**

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What an interesting function! Notice that $T(n) = 1 + T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ for $n > 2$. More importantly, we have $T(2)=0$, so we can actually "unfold" until we hit $T(2)$, not $T(1)$. We can see that:
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 1 + T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\
&=1 + \left(1 + T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)\right)\\
&=1 + \left(1 + \left(1 + T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)\right)\right)\\
& \vdots\\
&= \ell +T\left(\frac{n}{2^\ell}\right)
\end{align}

for some integer $\ell$. So $$T(n) = k-1 + T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}\right) = k-1+T(2) = k-1$$ where $k = \log(n)$. Your error was in attempting to "unfold" $T(2)$, when it makes no sense to do so if $T(2) = 0$.

Comment: This makes more sense. Can you show the first couple steps of the unfolding like I have? I can see that $2^{k}/2^{k-1}$ will give us $T(2)$ and $k-1$ however I’d like to know how you arrived at it starting from $T(n) = 1 + T(n/2)$ (how you unfolded until you reached $T(2)$ without explicitly stating the answer).

Comment: @udpcon Sure thing! I'll edit that in in a few minutes.

Comment: @udpcon As you can see, it's pretty much identical to yours. The only real error that you made is lumping in the case $n=2$ with the cases $n>2$!